# Does removing Softaculous affect the installed Apps?

Tags: vps

I researched about this and even asked my hosting provider, but they didn't give me an answer.

I am paying for a **Softaculous** license in a VPS.

I used it some time ago to install **WordPress** and **NextCloud**.

But I disabled the auto-update for both since I want to do that manually.

I want to remove Softaculous, because I am not using it anymore, but I wonder if that will have any effect on the already installed apps.

My hosting provider tells me to "just do it and see what happens", but I don't think this is the cleanest way to do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow instructions given in the official documentation, uninstalling Softaculous is only deleting its own files, you do not delete installed apps.

https://www.softaculous.com/docs/Uninstall